# Designate field Foo exclusive or field Bar as required in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema has properties `foo` and `bar`.  It is only allowed that one or the other exist when the document is saved. Not none, not both.

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    foo: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Foo' },
    bar: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Bar'}
  });
```

Is there a way for me to mark these fields required in such an 'exclusive or' way, or do I need to implement this save logic myself?

Comment: Use your own validation system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mongoose Schema Pre-save event to test for existence of one or another before mongoose executes the actual save.

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // do stuff
  next();
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: This seems super useful in general but specifically; if something causes me to not call `next()`, what is the proper way to send a response back indicating why the validation failed?

Comment: as per callback style, return first parameter as error: return next(err). create your own err and state the message etc.